# Where should I unregisterReceiver in my own view?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-custom-view

My view has to `registerReceiver` with `ACTION_TIME_TICK` action but I don't have any idea where I should un-register.

If I don't do this, I will have a leak.

Here is some relevant code:

```
public class TimeIndicator extends ViewSwitcher {

    private void build(final Context context) {

        this.addView(View.inflate(context, R.layout.time_indicator, null));

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
        context.registerReceiver(this.receiver, filter);
    }

    public final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i("onReceive", intent.getAction());
        }
    };
}
```

Where should i unregisterReceiver in my own view?

Comment: To register it in OnResume and unregister it in the OnPause.

Answer (score 3):

```
@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    //add your code.
    getContext().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good behavior, your view doesn't represent a context ( doesn't have clear life-cycle and doesn't have life-cycle callback methods -onPause, onCreate .... - )

So what you should do is regested that receiver at the first parent context object your view belongs to. if it is a fragment of an activity.

Then you can register the receiver at the : `onCreate()` of the parent.
and remove it when you don't want to receive updates anymore or in `onStop()`

Comment: I would say not onCreate() method should be used but rather onStart() method.