# Register to local broadcast inside a custom view

Tags: android, view, broadcastreceiver

I've created a custom view which can be placed on different places in the application. I can't avoid using a BroadcastReceiver inside the view to get messages from the rest of the application.

I've read it's not recommended ([Where should I unregisterReceiver in my own view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063039/where-should-i-unregisterreceiver-in-my-own-view)), but in case I choose to use it is there a place to unregister the view from the BroadcastManager?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you to use a LocalBroadcastManager. It's like a BroadcastReceiver whose Intents can only be seen inside your application.

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // your code here
    }
};

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    LocalBroadcastManager lbm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(MyClass.MY_ACTION);
    lbm.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: That's actually what I'm doing, but since I'm registering during the creation of a custom view (not an activity which has onDestroy etc) - I can't find a proper place to unregister my receiver.. so currently I don't :/

Comment: A view (or custom view) does not have a lifecycle like an activity or service, so you can't know when it's destroyed or hidden. You should control all register/unregister actions of all your views from the activity that contains them.

Comment: I'll take this as an answer, though I do wish that a custom view could be independent in this sense too, It's really limiting... If someone has an idea about that I'd love to hear, thanks.

Comment: @DrorFichman you could add an interface to your view that contains the activity/fragment lifecycle, then make sure you call it from the containing activity/fragment lifecycle events. Not a great solution but would work.

Answer (score 0):

As @vggonz Said a view does not have a clear lifecycle like an activity, However, if you register a broadcast receiver in `onAttachedToWindow()` and unregister `onDetachedFromWindow()`, it works as expected.

```
public class MyView extends View {

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("SOME_ACTION");
        filter.addAction("SOME_OTHER_ACTION");
        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //do something based on the intent's action
            }
        };
        getContext().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        if (receiver != null) {
            getContext().unregisterReceiver(receiver);
            receiver = null;
        }
    }
}
```